# Exclude explicit interface method with PostSharp attribute multicast

Tags: aop, multicast, postsharp, explicit-interface, explicit-implementation

Let's say I have an interface:

```
namespace MyCompany.Security
{
    public interface IMySecurable
    {
        string GetContext();
    }
}
```

Which is implemented by a number of classes, e.g.

```
namespace MyCompany.Repositories
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using MyCompany.Security;

    public class MyRepository : IMySecurable
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
        {
            // Repository logic
        }

        string IMySecurable.GetContext()
        {
            // Logic here
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using PostSharp attribute multicasting to apply my aspect (`MySecurityAspect`) to each class in a namespace.

```
[assembly: MySecurityAspect(AttributeTargetTypes = "MyCompany.Repositories.*", AttributePriority = 1)]
```

However I'm unable to figure out how to exclude explicit interface method implementations i.e.

```
string IMySecurable.GetContext()
{
    // Logic here
}
```

I have tried following the documentation [here](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/multicasting#title2), using this statement:

```
[assembly: MySecurityAspect(AttributeTargetMembers = "GetContext", AttributeExclude = true, AttributePriority = 2)]
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

**How can I exclude methods using attribute multicasting when they are explicit interface implementations?**

Comment: Have you tried to add AttributeTargetTypes to the exclude attribute?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/306-suppress-some-exception-logging-in-diagnostic-toolkit-configuration

> The attribute with exclude set to true effects only what was processed
>   to the point of occurrence of the exclude i.e. exclude will effect
>   only attributes occurring prior to exclude.

In other words, order of attributes is important.

If it wouldn't help, ask the question directly on http://support.sharpcrafters.com.

BTW: I found that to specify Postsharp aspects in PSProj file is more flexible, than adding attributes in a code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion although it doesn't really help. I have a support request open [here](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/521-override-base-class-aspect-in-derived-class).